# Build machine showing "Nuget missing packages" error when compiling. Compiles fine on dev machine

Tags: msbuild, nuget, cruisecontrol.net

I have a build machine running Cruise Control. 
This morning  I updated several Nuget packages on my Dev machine. After checking in I now get:

`error: This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them`

I've run `Nuget restore mySolutions.sln` on the server. The results say "all packages are already installed".

But when cruise control runs it still shows the error.

I've gone to the command line and for each project I have run "nugget install" which comes back with out any errors.

The original project was using nuget 2.1. I have installed 2.7 on the server and have used that for all of the command line installs

Comment: Just quick check : have you actually enabled "NuGet Package Restore" as error advising ? To do that - go to Tools->Options->Packages->General and check two checkboxes. Is an error still persists after that ?

Comment: in VS? On the dev machine or on the build machine?

Comment: Yes. On the machine where you facing issue. If you don't have VS installed on your build server, you can do it manually as NuGet docs advising : To enable package restore for build servers without Visual Studio installed, you can also set the environment variable EnableNuGetPackageRestore to "true".

Comment: the EVariable is set to true and the value in nuget.Targets  for restorepacakages is also set to true.

Comment: Can you produce full build log using /v:diag switch and post it somewhere ?

Comment: Try deleting everything in the packages folder on your build machine. NuGet thinks that a package already exists and so doesn't need restore if it finds the nupkg file. But it's possible that the contents of the nupkg file are not unzipped and saved along side the nupkg file, which will cause build failure.

Comment: Are you sure it all got checked in?? My first guess would be something is missing from source control.